# alert not working in html in phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, alert

I am trying this code in which alert should be displayed once application in loaded successfully in iphone. But this is not working. This is phonegap application and this application is index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>navigator.network.connection.type Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for PhoneGap to load
            // 
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
            checkConnection();
            }

            function checkConnection() {
                var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

                var states = {};
                states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
                //navigator.notification.alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
            }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>
          <a href="javascript:checkConnection()">Click</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
```

Comment: Where to write this code? I tried this but not working. No alert message is being displayed. :(

Comment: Your phonegap.js is for iOS? Try this https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-js/blob/master/src/ios/phonegap.js.base or this http://piwigo.org/dev/browser/extensions/piwigo_mobile/ios/www/phonegap.js

Comment: Thnx :) The Second link worked. It was version problem only. Now i am able to display alert in my app :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you properly set up the PhoneGap app? I noticed you have missed `<body onload="init();"  >`

The below code should work, I just typed it for you but have not compiled :-P

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>navigator.network.connection.type Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


            function init() {
              document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            function checkConnection() {
                var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

                var states = {};
                states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
                //navigator.notification.alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
            }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();>
    <h1>Check connection</h1>
    <p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>
          <a href="javascript:checkConnection()">Click</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is working on my simulator I just changed `js/phonegap-1.3.0.js` into `phonegap-1.2.0.js` according to my version and sorurce path. So check your phonegap js version and also check the it's path. Mine js file is in `www` folder where `index.html` is placed.

Comment: This was working for me for Hello World Project. But i just changed the code in index.html to test for connection. Is there any thing else i need to change when i change index.html?

Comment: what is your js version and path of js file??

Comment: 1.3.0. It's in js folder inside www folder.

Comment: i just did the same and changed my version and path as js/phonegap-1.3.0.js and it's working